# Generate JunitXml reports from cmake compiler errors

Tags: junit, cmake, makefile, continuous-integration, ctest

When running a unit-test suite with `ctest`, I can generate a JUnit-compatible test report xml file with
`ctest --output-junit=foo.xml`, containing all errors and successes of the test.

Can I somehow do the same during the compilation step with `cmake`/`make`/`gcc`?
Generate a test report file that contains all compiler errors?
Either in JunitXml or a similar format.

The unit-test-reports are automatically picked up by my ci-pipeline and presented in a nice table with each commit.

However, if a compilation error occurs, several mb of text logs have to be analyzed instead. It would be much easier to analyze if I could get a xml report.

Preferably I am searching for something that requires a minimum of modifications to the cmake files, ideally something that works just with some command line switches or environment variables.